# Android File encryption error

Tags: android

I'm trying to encrypt an audio file in Android. This file is then getting decrypted on the server-side by a PHP script. While encrypting the file I'm getting an Java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits

My code is as follows:

```
if(getFileToEncrypt.exists()){
            System.out.println("-----------FILE EXISTS--------------");
            secRand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            key = new BigInteger(128, secRand).toString(16);
            rawKey = key.getBytes();
            sKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(rawKey, "AES");
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sKeySpec);
            inputStream = new FileInputStream(getFileToEncrypt);
            byte[] byts = new byte[(int) getFileToEncrypt.length()];
            inputStream.read(byts);
            inputStream.close();
            encrypted = cipher.doFinal(byts);
            encryptedFile.createNewFile();
            ostr = new FileOutputStream(encryptedFile);
            ostr.write(encrypted);
            ostr.close();   
            System.out.println("--------FILE ENCRYPTION COMPLETE----------");

        }
```

**This works at times but otherwise ends up with an Exception.**
The stack trace is as follows:

```
07-08 15:38:02.865: W/System.err(16391): java.security.InvalidKeyException: Key length not 128/192/256 bits.
07-08 15:38:02.865: W/System.err(16391):    at        com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JCEBlockCipher.engineInit(JCEBlockCipher.java:570)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
        key = new BigInteger(128, secRand).toString(16);
        rawKey = key.getBytes();
```

That doesn't do what you think it does.

This code creates a hexadecimal string representing a number with at most 128 bits, then gets the bytes that encode that string in the platform default encoding.

This is (a) very low-entropy (each byte can only have one of 16 values) and (b) far longer than what you want (1 byte for every 4 bits of original data).

---

You should not be using numbers here at all; instead, you should generate random bytes directly, by calling the [`nextBytes()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html#nextBytes%28byte%5b%5d%29).

Comment: Thanks. What should I do to encrypt my files?

Comment: @Amey: Generate a random key using `nextBytes()`. Also, figure out a secure place to store the key.  If you store the key in the same place as the file, you won't add any security.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: Thanks SLaks, could you please give me some example code for the nextBytes() method?

Comment: @Amey: Just create a `byte[]` with the right number of bits (eg, `256 / 8), then call the method to populate it.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks, just trying it out now, will let you know how it goes

Comment: Hi @ SLaks, is this correct: secRand = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
    key = new BigInteger(128, secRand).toString(16);
    newKeyByte = new byte[32];
    secRand.nextBytes(newKeyByte);

Comment: @Amey: Yes, except that `key` should not exist.

Comment: Hi SLaks, I'm getting javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded while decrypting it on the server, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not using an IV during Encryption, is it to do with decryption?

Comment: Could you please explain @ SLaks, a bit confused here

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector  You need to learn much more about cryptography if you want to create something secure.